# Renaming RStudio project under version control

Tags: r, git, rstudio

What's the right way to rename an RStudio project (esp., when that project is under version control)?

E.g., I created an RStudio project with version control in "~/myproject". Then I decided I wanted to rename the project to "myproject1". So I

1. renamed "~/myproject" as "~/myproject1"
2. renamed "myproject.Rproj" as "myproject1.Rproj"
3. committed the "rename" changes with git via RStudio.

Everything seems to be fine. But I have a suspicion I'm missing something and that I'm going to be surprised by some project behavior down the line.

Comment: FWIW it sounds like you've done everything correctly here.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks.  Since I also wanted to change the name of the GitHub repo, I used `git remote set-url origin [GitHub repo URL]` See here: [https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)

Comment: For future travelers: If you made a README on repo initialization, you'll likely need to change the README.md header title as well

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your project is also an R package, you need to edit the DESCRIPTION file and change the value of "Package" property to reflect the new name.

Comment: Where is this description file? Running `find -name "DESCRIPTION"` inside of my project directory returned no results.

Comment: "If you project is also an R package." is it?

Comment: Ah. I see. No. Not a proper package. Got it.